# Active Scroll class State

Tags: html, css

I have 4 links and I want them to change add active to which section it has scrolled to.

but I don't want the hyper link feel when you hover I only want add the active to the link which selection is the current state.

```css
#pagemenu{
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 top: 40%;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 
}


#pagemenu ul{
 list-style: none;
 display: block;
 margin-left: 0;
}

.pagelink{
 display: block; 
 height: 38px;
 width: 200px;
 margin-bottom: 6px;
 border-left: 2px solid red;
 color: red;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}


.active2{
 background-color: #424242;
 border-left: 2px solid #e1b130;
 color: #e1b130;
}
​
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pagemenu">
 <a class="pagelink active2" href="#">Link Here</a>
 <a class="pagelink" href="#">Link Here</a>
 <a class="pagelink" href="#">Link Here</a>
 <a class="pagelink" href="#">Link Here</a>
</div>​
```

Comment: would you prefer javascript solution?

Comment: @repzero that would work.

Comment: answer posted for your perusal

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript. Here is how the snippet included in this question  is implemented

Get all anchor elements of class `pagelink`

Add a click event to these elements

Add a css class named `highlight` in your css stylesheet

When you click on an anchor tag you remove any highlighted background color from all elements and apply that background color only to the active anchor link clicked.

See snippet below

```js
function highlight(e) {
  for (var x = 0; x < all_anchors.length; ++x) {
    if (e.target != all_anchors[x]) {
      all_anchors[x].classList.remove("highlight")

    } else {
      all_anchors[x].classList.add("highlight")
    }
  }
}
all_anchors = document.getElementsByClassName("pagelink");
for (var x = 0; x < all_anchors.length; ++x) {
  all_anchors[x].addEventListener("click", highlight);
}
```

```css
#pagemenu {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#pagemenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.pagelink {
  display: block;
  height: 38px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  color: red;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active2 {
  background-color: #424242;
  border-left: 2px solid #e1b130;
  color: #e1b130;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #424242;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pagemenu">
  <a class="pagelink" href="#">Link Here</a>
  <a class="pagelink" href="#">Link Here</a>
  <a class="pagelink" href="#">Link Here</a>
  <a class="pagelink" href="#">Link Here</a>
</div>​
```